# Writing to file in a thread safe manner

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, file-system

I'm writing Stringbuilder to file asynchronously. This code takes control of a file, writes a stream to it and releases it. It deals with requests from asynchronous operations, which may come in at any time.

The `FilePath` is set per class instances (so the lock `Object` is per instance), but there is potential for conflict since these classes may share `FilePath`s. That sort of conflict, as well as all other types from outside the class instance, would be dealt with with retries.

Is this code suitable for its purpose? Is there a better way to handle this that means less (or no) reliance on the catch and retry mechanic?

Also how do I avoid catching exceptions that have occurred for other reasons?

```
public string Filepath { get; set; }
private Object locker = new Object();

public async Task WriteToFile(StringBuilder text)
    {
        int timeOut = 100;
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                //Wait for resource to be free
                lock (locker)
                {
                    using (FileStream file = new FileStream(Filepath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file, Encoding.Unicode))
                    {
                        writer.Write(text.ToString());
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            catch
            {
                //File not available, conflict with other class instances or application
            }
            if (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > timeOut)
            {
                //Give up.
                break;
            }
            //Wait and Retry
            await Task.Delay(5);
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your *requirements* are? That will make it easier to not over-engineer this.

Comment: There's a load test going on and every time a unit test is run it is logged. I think every unit test has it's own file so the lock on its own should be sufficient. If that's not the case, come to think of it, this try again method would probably be overwhelm and it would have to be a static lock. I think I'll just make it a simple lock and comment in my assumptions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**I'm not sure why this is async.**

Unless you have a good reason for write to the file asynchronously, this is wasted effort.

If you `lock` properly, this will work fine.  Your `locker` variable should be marked `static`.  You can then get away with something like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test
{   
    public class Writer
    {
        public string Filepath { get; set; }
        private static object locker = new Object();

        public void WriteToFile(StringBuilder text)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                using (FileStream file = new FileStream(Filepath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file, Encoding.Unicode))
                {
                    writer.Write(text.ToString());
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This assumes you don't have some other reason for making this async.

Comment: By making the lock object `static` you lose the capability of writing to several files at once because all instances of `Writer` will have to wait, no matter what file they are writing to.

Comment: If each instance of `Writer` points to a different file, then correct, you can use an instance locking object.  If you have two instances of `Writer` pointing at the same file, the locking will do nothing unless you use the `static` lock.